# Decode RTP G.722 payload

Tags: c#, rtp, codec

I am working on an application that retrieves audio from RTP streams. I have no problems with G.711 uLaw and ALaw, but I also have to deal with the G.722 protocol.
So far I've had no luck decoding it. I tried to use NAudio, which has a codec for it, without luck. The documentation of the codec in NAudio is very limited. 
Does anyone know a decent library with documentation or examples how to do this?

And if that library includes other codec, even better!

Snippet of my code thusfar, using NAudio. This code runs for each packet payload of 160 bytes: If anyone can spot an error or if you have suggestions, please let me know.

```
case RtpPacket.PayloadTypes.G722:
    G722CodecState state = new G722CodecState(64000, G722Flags.None);   
    G722Codec codec = new G722Codec();

    var length = packet.Payload.Length;
    var outputBuffer = new short[length*4];
    int decoded = codec.Decode(state, outputBuffer, packet.Payload, length);
```

Comment: Can you show me the sdp sip invite ? otherwise try to use as first step wireshark>Telephony>VoIP Call to listen to your incoming Calls. If it is okay, you are sure that your INVITE with SIP protocol is Ok and you are receiving the right payload and you can move to the next step : the codec

Comment: I understand your reasoning, but as I said, I have a complete running application that can handle G.711. I just need to handle some other codecs.

Comment: One thing I found out, and in retrospect it's logical:
Instead of creating a state and codec object for each packet, I now use these objects as class variables, where they live for the duration of the rtp stream. 
It is unfortunate that NAudio lacks documentation on that part, though I love the capabilities of this library.

Comment: So, if anyone can point me in the direction of a, preferably free, codec for G.723 and/or G.729, It would help me a lot!

Comment: An application that can handle G711 does not mean that it can handle G722 payloads as well it really depends on the other party. You need as first step send the right sdp with the right codec name, and the other party should handle it. For example you need to send the 'a' property like this: "a=rtpmap:9 g722/16000" in the Ok of SIP, to say to the other party that i want to use G722 as a codec. If you receive some RTP Packets, then you should be able to listen to your packet on wireshark. If you receive 0packets it means that the other party can not handle G722 at least with 16000Hz rate

Comment: once you receive the g722 rtp packets then you can move on to the decoding step

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear in my previous comment, but I solved the G.722 problem.

Comment: oh okay , glad to hear that , which rate are you using just for my knowledge : 8000 or 16000 ?

Comment: NAudio has a state flag that will magically reduce the rample rate back to 8kHz. I have not done a quality comparison between this setting and simply skipping every other sample which would also effect to 8kHz. This feels better.

Answer (score 1):

The settings I use now for my purpose are as follows:

class variables:

```
    private readonly G722CodecState _g722CodecState = new G722CodecState(64000, G722Flags.SampleRate8000);
    private readonly G722Codec _g722Codec = new G722Codec();
```

And within my rtp retrieval function:

```
case RtpPacket.PayloadTypes.G722:
    var length = packet.Payload.Length;
    var outputBuffer = new short[length];
    int decoded = _g722Codec.Decode(_g722CodecState, outputBuffer, packet.Payload, length);
```

It works like a charm!